# Make uppercase of result of StrLeft with cyrillic argument

Tags: cyrillic, xstring

I'm trying to uppercase first letters of the cyrillic string:

```
\StrLeft{абырвалг}{3}[\firstletters]
\firstletters
\MakeUppercase{\firstletters}
```

Result is lower case "абыабы".

The same operation under latin string works correct:

```
\StrLeft{abcdef}{3}[\firstletters]
\MakeUppercase{\firstletters}
```

returns "ABC"

MakeUppercase macro works correct if argument is string, not macro:

```
\MakeUppercase{абы}
```

returns "АБЫ"

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cyrillic character is not a single byte for `\StrLeft` and full expansion of it will make things very difficult, most likely producing strange errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\uc}[2][1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\IeC\@firstofone
  \protected@edef\dmitry@temp{#2}%
  \noexpandarg
  \expandafter\StrLeft\expandafter{\dmitry@temp}{#1}[\dmitry@temp]%
  \MakeUppercase{\dmitry@temp}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\uc{абырвалг}

\uc[3]{абырвалг}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I first get a LICR representation of the input string, then use `\StrLeft` with just a one level expansion, to avoid errors. In the second example, we'll be left with `\cyra\cyrb\cyryery`, which `\MakeUppercase` is able to work with.